# How to change a value in line of config file python

Tags: python, parameters, config

```
file = open("my_config", "r")
for line in file:
    change line to "new_line"
```

How I can change a value of parameter in line.

Comment: Welcome to So. Please provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can be of any help.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear, you open a config file (may we have a example of the structure? If it is a JSON file or similar, it could be easier), loop trough all lines of it and want to change one line?

The best way would be to recreate the file, stocked in a string and then rewrite it.

```
file = open("my_config", "w")
str_file = ""
for line in file:
    # Change the line here
    str_file += line+'\n'

str_file = str_file.strip() #To remove the last \n

file.write(str_file)
file.close()
```

EDIT: with your comment QA Answser, I'ld go with:

```
file = open("my_config", "w")
str_file = ""
for line in file:
    if (line.split(':')[0] == 'SECURITY_LEVEL'):
        line = 'SECURITY_LEVEL:' + VALUE #your new value here
    str_file += line+'\n'

str_file = str_file.strip() #To remove the last \n

file.write(str_file)
file.close()
```

Comment: This should rather be a comment as it is totally unclear how the file structure is. It may be huge and "recreate" 10gb is surely not the "best way" to go.

Comment: SHOW_RIDGES                        = false;
ENROLL_MODE                        = 0;
MATCH_MODE                         = 0;

// SECURITY_LEVEL: 0-100
SECURITY_LEVEL                     = 33;

Comment: I want to change the security_level value

Comment: So in the code I provided, you can check at the 4th line, if line.split(':')[0]=="SECURITY_LEVEL" and change the second value!

Comment: I put the changes to make in the EDIT, hope it closes your problem!